# Haunted subdirectory -- can't open files in it unless I move them

Tags: windows-10, filenames, open

I have some subdirectories from which perfectly good files cannot be opened, unless I move them out of the directory into another directory.  And, if I then move them back into the original (bad? haunted) directory I can't open them.

I just ran __   chkdsk d: /r   __  (from cmd.exe as administrator) and got back a report that everything is perfect on my new data drive (WD Gold Enterprise Class SATA HDD 10TB).

So far, I've only found this problem with MS Word (2013) and .pdf files, but haven't looked further yet.  Word appears to open the files but the just presents a blank document.  Acrobat responds to the .pdf file with "There was an error opening this document.  The path does not exist."  PDF Viewer Plus just says "This file cannot be found."

If I *copy* the subdirectory to another subdirectory, the file opens OK.  If I *move* the subdirectory to another subdirectory, the file won't open.  If I move the copied subdirectory (that works) to overwrite the haunted subdirectory the file won't open. If I copy the subdirectory to another directory, so it works, then delete the original subdirectory, then move or copy the subdirectory back where the original one was, the file doesn't work.

Another quirk, when deleting the bad subdirectory, I get a message "Do you want to permanently delete this folder?  The folder contains items whose names are too long for the recycle bin."  I don't think that's literally true.

I don't know how many haunted subdirectories I have on my data drive.  So far, I've only found them under one directory.  Ideally, I'd like to find 'em all and fix 'em all in one fell swoop.

Background:  Win10 64 mongrel computer (built it myself), all Win updates are current.
I'm recovering pretty well from losing my data drive.  After first desperately conglomerating every copy of my old files I could (from Carbonite, and a USB backup drive with irritatingly imperfect backups), I set about deleting duplicates using Duplicate Cleaner Pro.  Because there were high volumes and I really didn't need to protect the copies I was deleting, I used the setting to delete them faster by not going through Windows Shell.  Also, in copying files back and forth between my new drive and my backup drive, I also used TeraCopy to speed things up.  I've a feeling if I'd just Windows Shell do the moving, this wouldn't have happened, but moving terabytes of data takes a long time, especially when the USB drive is SMR.

"Include all the information someone would need to answer your question," right?  This problem seems so weird that I don't know what to include.  I could dump a lot more information here, but have no idea what might be helpful.

Comment: Posting a question, then my own solution, seems like cheating, like I'm trying to give myself forum points.  I re-did it this way at Kamil Maciorowski's recommendation.

Comment: Well, the site was [deliberately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) programmed so that you'd get points for posting your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the course of trying to describe it, I solved it. I sometimes use long file names, to describe what's in the file.

A file with a long name in a primary directory might be fine, but move it into a subdirectory of a subdirectory and Windows can't handle it -- apparently Windows processes file names including the directory names.

So, the solution is just to move those files (or their subdirectories) back to higher level directories, to deal with 'em.

My problem was that I was trying to figure out what was wrong with the file, or the directory, when the problem was just being caused by the long filename and directory placement.